# Set Frame Not Sizing UIView Correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, xib

I must be missing something related to frame and/or auto layout... I am loading in a simple view via a xib file (1 UIImageView and 2 Labels) multiple times within a UIScrollView (technically inside a single "content" view within the scroll view), but when I load it in and try to set the frame, the size doesn't match what I specify. I want each view to be 250px by 200px and here is my code...

```
var i: CGFloat = 0
for package in packageList {
    let view = UINib(nibName: "PackageDetail", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    view.frame = CGRectMake((i * 250), 0, 250, 200)
    self.scrollSubView.addSubview(view)
    i++
}
```

And here is what I get - it looks like each view is spaced 250px apart (as desired), but they are more like 420px wide - I have added a semi transparent orange background for illustration. I am explicitly specifying that they are 250px wide, why is this happening? The rest of the storyboard uses auto layout and these views have no constraints - do I need to add a bunch of constraints programmatically?

[image]

Comment: where did u place that piece of code? `viewdidload`?

Comment: My code is in `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer for your question, but I believe you should be using an `UICollectionView` instead for this matter.

By using an `UICollectionView`, you are able to accomplish what you're trying to achieve with the `UIScrollView` and subviews.

[UICollectionView Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1)

[UICollectionView Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewBasics/CollectionViewBasics.html)

Comment: Great call. Can't believe I didn't think of that - I'm actually using a UICollectionView in another area of the app.  Thanks much!